# How does the second function get a data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does the `start` and `history` gets a value?. Where it came from?. I am reading this [LINK](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#c_YeYw47ylC5).

If anyone knows please explain it.

**Output**

> (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)

```js
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

Comment: From Here `return find(1, "1");`. When `findSolution` is called, the inner function is called by this statement.

Comment: `start` and `history` are arguments of the `find(start, history) {...}` function. Every time `find()` is called, values are passed to it, e.g., `find(1, "1")`.

Comment: correct me if Im wrong. `findSolution` can return the inner function?. Like in the code?.

Comment: `findSolution()` doesn't return the inner function, it returns the result of calling the inner function.

Comment: @nnnnnn ow sorry.. That's what I mean. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {     // <--- NOTICE DECLARATIONS HERE
      /* SNIP */
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }       //    ^--- FUNCTION CALLS HERE
  return find(1, "1");  // <--- AND HERE
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

I've snipped out some irrelevant details to this question and inserted some comments. As you can see, the function `find` is declared with the two arguments in question `start` and `history`. `find` is first called with `1` as the value for `start` and `"1"` as the value for `history`. Following this, the `find` function recursively calls itself with new values for these arguments.